# Docker stops previous running container with the same image. Why?

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-for-mac

I'm on Docker for Mac 1.13.0

When I run `docker run -d cassandra:3.9` each time it kills previous container. I can not start more than one instance. It works as expected with `nginx:latest` though, i.e. starts multiple instances.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

give it a different name

`docker run -d --name cassandra1 cassandra:3.9`

and then

`docker run -d --name cassandra2 cassandra:3.9`

Comment: Same result. I've reinstalled Docker 4 Mac and it solved the problem. However the reason is still unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this might be a docker 1.13 problem. I dont see this issue on docker 1.12.6 on mac.